# Taking a screenshot calls drawRect

Tags: ios, uiview, screenshot, drawrect

I'm taking a screenshot of the current view:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
self.bitmapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

In some cases this calls `-drawRect:`, but not always. Why is that?

p.s. This appears to be a buggy behavior.

Comment: try to change the self.bounds.size to self.frame.size

Comment: self.bounds.size = self.frame.size, so it doesn't matter.